# Compare a row with previous 3 rows

Tags: r

I have the following data frame

```
id<-1:10
x<-c(240, 220, 200, 180, 160, 170, 120, 130, 80, 60)
df<-data.frame(id, x)
```

I would like to add a column (named "valid") that indicates if an x value is **smaller than the 3 previous x values**. If the x value fulfills this criteria then the corresponding row in "valid" must = 1

Ideally, I would like the x values to only be included in the criteria if they get a "valid" value = 1

I anticipate NAs in in the first 3 rows of the "valid" column.

The output would look like this:

```
id<-1:10
x<-c(240, 220, 200, 180, 160, 170, 120, 130, 80, 60)
valid<-c(NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1)
df1<-data.frame(id, x, valid)

id   x     valid
1   240      NA
2   220      NA
3   200      NA
4   180       1
5   160       1
6   170       0
7   120       1
8   130       0
9   80        1
10  60        1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are only 3 values that you need to check you can use `lag` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
df %>% mutate(valid = +(x < lag(x) & x < lag(x, 2) & x < lag(x, 3)))
```

A more general solution would be to use rolling operations with a window size to look back to so that it can easily be extended even if you have to test last 10 values.

```
df %>% mutate(valid = +(x < lag(rollapplyr(x, 3, min, fill = NA))))

#   id   x valid
#1   1 240    NA
#2   2 220    NA
#3   3 200    NA
#4   4 180     1
#5   5 160     1
#6   6 170     0
#7   7 120     1
#8   8 130     0
#9   9  80     1
#10 10  60     1
```

The `+` at the beginning converts the logical values (`TRUE`/`FALSE`) to integer values (`1`/`0`).